# FastAPI - how to make a CLI Tools for an Application in Docker

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, fastapi

I have a FastApi python application:

1. I got Postres DB from Docker image
2. Made all the stuff needed - models, schemas, put it to db with alembic, started server with uvicorn
3. Made sure everything works with FastApi Swagger UI: all my POSTs and GETs are working fine.

So now, according to the task, I need to make CLI with three commands:
make run - to build and run project
make db-init - connect to db
help - show some hint on what my app does

And in general the application should be launched through docker-compose.

At this point I don't even know how to google properly :)
Could you please explain - what I should do? Should I add cli.py to my application with some commands?
I suppose, somehow the commands I did in a commandline - docker-compose for postgres, uvicorn for server, alembic for db init - should be executed when my application is started.
Where should I write that code?

So, could you please shortly tell a sequence of my next actions?

I have a working FastAPI app and now I need to make it portable with demanded CLI commands and dockerized.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your solution will involve a docker container running postgres and another docker container running your FastAPI app and a makefile. Make is a little language for scripting builds.

Comment: 1. Read about [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). 2. Define recipes in Makefile.

Comment: (Make's main benefit is for declaring what commands need to run to build a set of output files from a set of input files; I wouldn't necessarily reach for it as a general-purpose scripting tool.)